# Unable to Parse string response

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

This is the response I tried to parse and try to get the value in the separate strings,

```
response = 
  "Data1{
      key1='4722**********6',
      key2='2107',
      key3=value{
           value1='226',
           value2=passed,
           value3=tracked,
           value4=noted
      },
      isChecked=true
  }"
```

but unable to parse the response, like

```
String Datas = "Data1{key1='4722**********6', key2='2107', key3=value{value1='226', 
              value2=passed,value3=tracked, value4=noted}, isChecked=true}";
String data = Datas.substring(5);
//String data1 = data.replaceAll("\"", "");
try {
    JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject((data)); //JsonObject
    
    String strKey1= dataObject.getString("key1");
    String strKey2= dataObject.getString("key2");
    String strKey3= dataObject.getString("key3");

    JSONObject strValueObj = new JSONObject(strKey3);
    String strValue1= strValueObj.getString("value1");
    String strValue2= strValueObj.getString("value2");
    String strValue3= strValueObj.getString("value3");
    String strValue4= strValueObj.getString("value4");
```

Will normal String parsing work or is it correct to parse using JSON? Can anyone please help me on parse the string response.

Comment: The data string is not in the JSON format as keys and values are not in double-quotes. So, to parse it you need to build your own parser as this is not a valid JSON String.

Comment: Yes, it is not a valid JSON String, the response is coming from hardware can't change the format. then how do I parse, is there any other solution?

Comment: Add your exactly response that you want to convert it to json , i can write a code to change it , its about keys not values. you can do it yourself of course .the code will be like this : String json = Datas.replaceAll("=", "\":");

Comment: This is the exact response, "Data1{key1='4722**********6', key2='2107', key3=Key3{value1='226', 
              value2=passed,value3=tracked, value4=noted}, isChecked=true}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do some data transformations to achive JSON format:

```
private static final String KEY3 = "key3";
private static final String VALUE = "value";

void extractData() throws JSONException {
    String Datas = "Data1{key1='4722**********6', key2='2107', key3=value{value1='226', value2=passed,value3=tracked, value4=noted}, isChecked=true}";
    String data = Datas.substring(5);
    String dataAsJson = data.replaceAll("=", ":");
    
    if (dataAsJson.indexOf(KEY3) > -1) {
        StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder(dataAsJson.replaceFirst(VALUE, "{" + VALUE + ":"));
        dataBuilder.insert(dataAsJson.indexOf("}", dataAsJson.indexOf(KEY3)) + KEY3.length() - 1, "}");
        dataAsJson = dataBuilder.toString();
    }
    JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject((dataAsJson));
    String strKey1= dataObject.getString("key1");
    String strKey3= dataObject.getString("key3");

    JSONObject key3Obj = new JSONObject(strKey3);
    String value = key3Obj.getString("value");
    JSONObject valueObj = new JSONObject(value);
    String value1 = valueObj.getString("value1");
}
```

It works but for sure is not the most elegant solution and might not work if the input would change it's structure.

Edit: new input:

```
        String Datas = "Data1{key1='4722**********6', key2='2107', key3=value{value1='226', value2=passed,value3=tracked, value4=noted}, isMasked=true}";
    String data = Datas.substring(5);
    String dataAsJson = data.replaceAll("=", ":");

    if (dataAsJson.contains(KEY3)) {
        StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder(dataAsJson.replaceFirst(VALUE, "{" + VALUE + ":"));
        dataBuilder.insert(dataAsJson.indexOf("}", dataAsJson.indexOf(KEY3)) + KEY3.length() - 1, "}");
        dataAsJson = dataBuilder.toString();
    }
    JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject((dataAsJson));
    String strKey1 = dataObject.getString("key1");
    String strKey3 = dataObject.getString("key3");

    JSONObject key3Obj = new JSONObject(strKey3);
    String value = key3Obj.getString("value");
    JSONObject valueObj = new JSONObject(value);
    String value1 = valueObj.getString("value1");
```

Comment: throws error
org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 0 of :'4722**********6', key2:'2107', key3:{value:{value1:'226', value2:passed,value3:tracked, value4:noted}}, isChecked:true},
The response structure will not change, once parsed is good to go

Comment: Did you copy my code or mixed it with yours as well? Cause for me it seems like you used additional substring which cut "{key1=".

Comment: Worked perfectly!. my mistake, typo in my line Datas.substring(10); Thanks Bro!

Comment: How do I parse if the  same data come like this, "Data1{key1='4722**********6', key2='2107', key3=value{value1='226', value2=passed,value3=tracked, value4=noted}, isMas}ked=true}";

Comment: throws exception org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 122.

Comment: Well u have to check what is wrong with JSON and fix it - in that case it's this fragment - "isMas}ked", so have to get rid of that "}".

Comment: The actual repsonse is isMasked, after parsing like this,   StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder(dataAsJson.replaceFirst(VALUE, "{" + VALUE + ":"));
        dataBuilder.insert(dataAsJson.indexOf("}", dataAsJson.indexOf(KEY3)) + KEY3.length() - 1, "}");
        dataAsJson = dataBuilder.toString();
    } response changed like this isMas}ked. In this case have to work here, i think.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. How new input looks like?

Comment: The actual input is
Data1{key1='4722**********6', key2='2107', key3=value{value1='226', value2=passed,value3=tracked, value4=noted}, isMasked=true}"
after this line,
dataBuilder.insert(dataAsJson.indexOf("}", dataAsJson.indexOf(KEY3)) + KEY3.length() - 1, "}"); 
The actual string is achanged as 
Data1{key1='4722**********6', key2='2107', key3=value{value1='226', value2=passed,value3=tracked, value4=noted}, isMas}ked=true}"
Did you check the string 'isMasked'  changed as isMas}ed, that means it insert '}' at unwantedly. So the unterminated jsonException raised.
Hope you understand.

Comment: I understand what are you saying I am just not sure why it is not working. I think u might skipped some lines from my answer. I've added code with new input to my anwser (I can't add it to comment).